# Network via ieee1394 is unreachable (PC and laptop)

Tags: networking, ping, firewire

I decided to connect my PC to the laptop via firewire. All interfaces are up, but no packets can be send/recieved.

I'm using Linux Slackware64-current (kernel 2.6.37.4)
Laptop (Dell Vostro 3700) has this adapter:

```
root@trium:~# lspci | grep 1394
14:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd FireWire Host Controller (rev 01)
```

Old ieee1394 stack was removed in new kernels. thats why I use new:

```
root@trium:~# modprobe firewire-net
root@trium:~# lsmod | grep fire
firewire_net           12930  0 
firewire_ohci          27301  0 
firewire_core          51107  2 firewire_net,firewire_ohci
```

dmesg shows:

```
firewire_net: firewire0: IPv4 over FireWire on device 47203fc0434fc000
firewire_net: max_rec 0 out of range
firewire_core: refreshed device fw0
```

1st string is good, but the 2nd is strange for me. what does it mean? maybe it is the source of the problem?
ok. lets configure the interface:

```
root@trium:~# ifconfig firewire0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
root@trium:~# ifconfig
firewire0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 47-20-3F-C0-43-4F-C0-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:20 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2445 (2.3 KiB)  TX bytes:2445 (2.3 KiB)
```

Same configuration steps were made on my PC. OS is the same. FireWire device -

```
05:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev 46)
```

dmesg showed:

```
firewire_net: firewire0: IPv4 over FireWire on device 4d5a900003000000
firewire_net: max_rec 0 out of range
firewire_core: refreshed device fw0
```

interface configuration -

```
root@bium:~# ifconfig firewire0 192.168.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0
root@bium:~# ifconfig
firewire0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 4D-5A-90-00-03-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:20 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:70120 (68.4 KiB)  TX bytes:70120 (68.4 KiB)
```

Now lets ping PC from laptop -

```
root@trium:~# ping -c 3 192.168.1.3
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.3 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
pipe 3
```

Yes. the cable is connected. Laptop has 4pin port, and PC has 6pin port. AFAIK 6pin uses two pins for power supplyment. I have the coresponding cable, so i don't think that the problem is here.

thats all. thanks

Comment: Not really a programming question, belongs on serverfault. That being said, did you add a default route for that new interface? Host unreachable suggests that you configured the interface properly, but didn't give it a proper gateway/network setup and the packets have nowhere to go.

Comment: I didn't set any route. This is direct connection. Am I right? Also I made my default eth0 down.

Comment: 'host unreachable' suggests that ARP didn't work.  I'd run tcpdump on firewire0 to see what's going on.